# Information Extraction and Relation Extraction with Stanford NLP for python

Tags: python, stanford-nlp, extract, information-extraction, pycorenlp

How do I do extract the names of some companies from a bunch of documents using the Stanford core NLP for Python?

Here is a sample of my Data :

> ‘3Trucks Inc (‘3Trucks’ or the Company) is a tech-enabled long-haul
>   B2B digital platform matching cargo owners with long-haul freight
>   needs and truck owners who can service them, through its
>   internally-developed digital platform.founded in 2016, 3Trucks is
>   headquartered in California and has leased offices in Boston and
>   Florida. Some of their top clients are, Google,IBM and Nokia
>
> 3Trucks was founded in 2010, with Mr. Mark Robert as its CEO and John
>   Mclean as a Partner and CTO.'

I want to output for Information extraction:

```
3Truck
```

I want to output for Relation extraction:

```
('3truck', founded '2010'),
('John Mclean', 'Partner')
('3truck',client 'Google')
```

Comment: could you show us your code please?

Comment: What intrigues me about this question is how come 3Truck is the only entity you are interested in and how come say Mr. Mark Robert does not figure in any of its relations.  Also, by Information Extraction, is Entity Extraction meant here?  I think the current answer givers have assumed that in exploring other tools, written in Python, which could perform a similar task.

Answer (score 1):

normally Named entity recognition will be used for such applications, but NER can only classify into some categories.

```
from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag, ne_chunk
from nltk.chunk import tree2conlltags

sentence = "Mark and John are working at Google."
print(tree2conlltags(ne_chunk(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentence))
"""[('Mark', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), 
    ('and', 'CC', 'O'), ('John', 'NNP', 'B-PERSON'), 
    ('are', 'VBP', 'O'), ('working', 'VBG', 'O'), 
    ('at', 'IN', 'O'), ('Google', 'NNP', 'B-ORGANIZATION'), 
    ('.', '.', 'O')] """
```

For your application you have to train the Named entity recognition with respect to data , you are going to ask [Training NER](https://nlpforhackers.io/training-ner-large-dataset/)

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty simple,
You can use Spacy NER ( Natural language Entity recognition) to do your task.It has a set of pretrainded models to idenitfy different entities.